# Working around IP whitelisting with Hyperforce

Tags: api, ip-whitelisting, hyperforce

With the Hyperforce upgrade, Salesforce officially stopped supporting IP whitelisting as a security solution for API connections. We  have a couple of 3rd parties that require IP whitelisting of Salesforce servers, but on our new HyperForce instance, we can't provide them with more than the current IP address from which our requests are being sent to them.

Since there's no way to predict when the IP address is going to change, there's a risk of the connection breaking at any given moment.

We've been thinking about a workaround and one of the solutions could be an API Gateway with a fixed IP (whitelisted by 3rd party) that sits in the middle and forwards any request from Salesforce to the 3rd party service, and sends back the response to our Salesforce instance.

We'd ideally not want to set this up from scratch in our own data center but would like to use an online service for this. Preferably as simple to set up and maintain as possible, as the client is not very tech-savvy.

What alternatives should we consider?

Comment: Salesforce does provide you with all the IP addresses. They just don't guarantee they won't change. I've whitelisted them and haven't had an issue yet in six months.

Comment: Hi @Kasper. That's right, you can find them after searching for a bit. It's a long list of IP ranges and our 3rd party is basically also limiting the amount of whitelisting they want to do. I'm looking for something I can install for my client that is 'worry-free'..

Comment: I don't think you need to whitelist them all, only the ones for the region your Salesforce server is in. In my case that was three IP addresses. I get your point though, a third party system would be the worry-free way to go. Unfortunately, I don't know of any.

Comment: Okay, I shouldn't have said that. Of course, right after commenting that our IP addresses hadn't changed in half a year, they changed :P. They actually added 4 to our region. Have you had any luck finding a service for this?